# JS triggered checkbox's checked attr doesn't dynamically change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

My problem is really simple, i have a hidden checkbox and a custom fake checkbox which triggers the real one. I've tried lots of various methods but `click` function works only at the begining than stops.

I've and searhed alike questions on stackoverflow but coun't find a problem which similar to mine. Thank you for your time.

[**Here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CVWWn/2/)

**html:**

```
<div class="fl">
    <span class="tri_checkbox"></span>
    <input class="hidden_checkbox" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.tri_checkbox',function() {
  if ( !$(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
    $(this).parent().find('input.hidden_checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  }else{
    $(this).parent().find('input.hidden_checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

Comment: don't use .attr to change properties. It's for attributes only.

Comment: And don't use removeAttr to reset an attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to set the checked property

```
$(document).on('click', '.tri_checkbox', function () {
    $(this).next().prop('checked', function (_, checked) {
        return !checked;
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Eb94M/)

1. You can use .next() here since the span and the input are siblings
2. Use toggleClass() to change the class

Read: [Attributes vs. Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Answer (score 3):

Shorten your code up and try this:

```
$(this).toggleClass("selected");
$(this).parent(".fl").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).hasClass("selected"));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CVWWn/4/

Or just use one big chain:

```
$(this).toggleClass("selected").parent(".fl").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).hasClass("selected"));
```

Big chain: http://jsfiddle.net/CVWWn/5/

Answer (score 1):

- Dont use if (!hasClass) {} else {}, make it in the right logic in the
  first place! :)
- .parent().find() = siblings()
- use .prop()

.

```
$(document).on('click','.tri_checkbox',function() {
          if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).siblings('input.hidden_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
          }
        else {
            $(this).siblings('input.hidden_checkbox').prop('checked', 'checked');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
          }
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVWWn/7/)